# How to insert scheduled time to log every time I reschedule a task

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I need a feature for logging time to the task LOG every time I schedule/reschedule task.
It musts work like so: every time I press C-c C-s new schedule time is added to the LOG.
Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Read the [Progress Logging](https://orgmode.org/manual/Progress-Logging.html#Progress-Logging) section of the manual.

Comment: Read use case in the question: "It musts work like so: every time I press C-c C-s new schedule time is added to the LOG."

Comment: Apologies: I sent you to the wrong section. Read the [Inserting deadlines or schedules](https://orgmode.org/manual/Inserting-deadline_002fschedule.html#Inserting-deadline_002fschedule) section of the manual. Caveat: it will only log it if the scheduled time changes from what it was before.

Comment: Thank you. `org-log-reschedule` is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `NickD` pointed out in comments to the question `org-log-reschedule` in `org-mode`'s manuaul does the thing.